# why does this javascript add () function for a linked list return node?

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I'm working through understanding how this singly linked list implementation works in JavaScript.  Specifically, the return statements on lines 23 and 35 in the add() method.

-- On line 23, why would we return node, instead of using 'return'; instead? 
-- On line 35, why would we return node when it doesn't seem to affect the functionality of the code either way?

Thanks!

```
    // Constructors (Node and SinglyList)
    function Node(data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }

    function SinglyList() {
        this._length = 0;
        this.head = null;
    }

    //Add Method

    SinglyList.prototype.add = function(value) {
        var node = new Node(value),
            currentNode = this.head;

        if(!currentNode) {
            this.head = node;
            this._length++;

            // return the new Node object. (why can't we just use return; here?)
            return node;
        }

        //USE CASE 2: NON-EMPTY LIST
        while (currentNode.next) {
            currentNode = currentNode.next; 
        }
        currentNode.next = node;

        this._length++;

        // return statement doesn't seem to do anything here.
        return node;
    };

    var list = new SinglyList();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add('foo');
    console.log(list.head);
```

Comment: 'Why does it need to' - It doesn't _need_ to, but it's there in case you or someone else want that feature later.

Comment: Good point.  Changed question wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of this SinglyList simply wanted to implement it that way.

In the use case that the user wants a reference to the new node that was created in the list, they could save that rather than finding that node again after the add. There is no single *correct* way to implement a LinkedList, and a lot is left up to interpretation.

In the event that you don't want the reference after adding the node, you can just choose to ignore the returned element.